# Play 1.2.5 error pages. Action not found

Tags: playframework

How to show 404 Error page in Play 1.2.5 for all actions except the ones that I defined?
Right now I'm getting action not found.

You can find it on http://www.buzwad.com/

Answer (score 0):

Open the `app/views/errors` directory. You'll likely see a 404.html and a 500.html. Make a copy of 404.html and name it 401.html, or 403.html or whatever HTTP status code you like. Then customise the copied files to suit your needs.